# How to correctly pass the body of my apex class to the visualforce page

Tags: salesforce, apex, visualforce

I have an apex class which has a getApexClassInfo() method:

```
public with sharing class ApexParser {
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static ApexClass getApexClassInfo(String ApexClassName) {
        ApexClass ApexClassBody = [
            SELECT Name, Body
            FROM ApexClass         
            WHERE Name =: ApexClassName
        ];
        return ApexClassBody;
    }
}
```

The method returns the body of the class that was selected in the combobox

Tell me how to correctly pass the ApexClassBody value to the visualforce page

```
<apex:page controller="ApexParser" renderAs="pdf" applyHtmlTag="false" showHeader="false" cache="true" readOnly="true">
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <h1>Test to see if this will generate</h1>
            <apex:outputText value="{   ??????   }"/>
        <h2><p>END</p></h2>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: The way you plan to use it in Visualforce (with `{!mergeFields}`) doesn't like  static methods. They're supposed to be "normal", non-static. If you really want to keep it as static - read up about [remoting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_configuring_request.htm) ? Post more code and maybe a screenshot or a mockup how you expect it to work. How do you specify the class name. Is the picklist VF `apex:inputSelect` or plain html `<select>` or what. "combobox" and "static" sounds like you're converting LWC/aura to VF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this. Basically, you can use a `public getter` to store your 'Body' in and then bind that to a variable in your Visualforce code. Be sure to call your `getApexClassInfo()` method somewhere too.

```
public static String body { get; set; }

@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static ApexClass getApexClassInfo(String ApexClassName) {
    ApexClass ApexClassBody = [
        SELECT Name, Body
        FROM ApexClass         
        WHERE Name =: ApexClassName
    ];
    body = ApexClassBody.Body;
    return ApexClassBody;
}


<apex:page controller="ApexParser" renderAs="pdf" applyHtmlTag="false" showHeader="false" cache="true" readOnly="true">
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <h1>Test to see if this will generate</h1>
            <apex:outputText value="{!body}"/>
        <h2><p>END</p></h2>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```